Using 2 enumproperties , at init selecting one item at index 4 select in the other list one item as same index, is it possible to have it at index 0?
I'm using the Gorgeous example as it is what I want to use and it's a great example ;)
see How to show limited enum items?
The problem when I run the script, is if I select in first list the item at index 4 and I switch to the last list, which have only one item here, the fact that the index is at 4 it won't select by default the first item of the last list, it will try to select the 5th item and because there's only one item, this item is not selected
So is it possible to do so ? at least select the first item when switching to the last list  ?
Thanks
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Test"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False
        
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(context.scene, 'enum_type', expand=True)
        text = 'Enum 1-5' if context.scene.enum_type == "FIRST" else 'Enum 6-10'
        col.prop(context.scene, 'enum', text=text, expand=True)


enum_type = (
    ('FIRST', 'First', ''),
    ('LAST', 'Last', ''),
)


def get_enum_items(self, context):
    get_enum_items.items.clear()
    if context.scene.enum_type == "FIRST":
        get_enum_items.items = [
            ('1', '1', ''),
            ('2', '2', ''),
            ('3', '3', ''),
            ('4', '4', ''),
            ('5', '5', ''),
        ]
    elif context.scene.enum_type == "LAST":
        get_enum_items.items = [
            ('6', '6', ''),
        ]
    return get_enum_items.items


get_enum_items.items = []


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name='Enums', items=get_enum_items)
    bpy.types.Scene.enum_type = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name='Types', items=enum_type)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


Use the EnumProperty's update callback.
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Test"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False
        
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(context.scene, 'enum_type', expand=True)
        text = 'Enum 1-5' if context.scene.enum_type == "FIRST" else 'Enum 6-10'
        col.prop(context.scene, 'enum', text=text, expand=True)


enum_type = (
    ('FIRST', 'First', ''),
    ('LAST', 'Last', ''),
)

items_1 = [
    ('1', '1', ''),
    ('2', '2', ''),
    ('3', '3', ''),
    ('4', '4', ''),
    ('5', '5', ''),
]

items_2 = [
    ('6', '6', ''),
    ('7', '7', ''),
]


def get_enum_items(self, context):
    if self.enum_type == "FIRST":
        return items_1
    elif self.enum_type == "LAST":
        return items_2
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Unexpected enum_type: {self.enum_type}")


def update_enum_type(self, context):

    index = self['enum']
    items = get_enum_items(self, context)
    
    if len(items) - 1 < index:
        self['enum'] = 0


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name='Enums', items=get_enum_items)
    bpy.types.Scene.enum_type = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name='Types', items=enum_type, update=update_enum_type)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


is there a way to access or set an item with index outside of update_enum_type ? using bpy.context.scene.enum = '6' to set the item is ok but it depends on the value. Thanks

self is bpy.context.scene in this case as you assign enum to bpy.types.Scene. So bpy.context.scene['enum'] = 0.
